# How to detect is GZIP is enabled by PHP?

Tags: gzip

I have created PHP script for GZIP compression settings added to .htaccess file:

```
// Ścieżka do pliku .htaccess
$htaccess_path = ABSPATH . '.htaccess';

// Sprawdź, czy plik .htaccess istnieje i jest zapisywalny
if (file_exists($htaccess_path) && is_writable($htaccess_path)) {

    // Tworzenie reguł dla mod_expires.c
    $gzip_compression = '
        # BHLD GZIP SETTINGS START
        <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            # Włączenie kompresji GZIP
            SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        
            # Ustawienia dla kompresji GZIP
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
        
            # Nie kompresuj obrazków
            SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
        </IfModule>
        # BHLD GZIP SETTINGS END
        ';
        
            // Odczytaj zawartość aktualnego pliku .htaccess
            $current_htaccess_content = file_get_contents($htaccess_path);
        
            // Usuń istniejące reguły mod_expires.c i mod_headers.c, jeśli istnieją
            $current_htaccess_content = preg_replace('/# BHLD GZIP SETTINGS START(.*)# BHLD GZIP SETTINGS END/s', '', $current_htaccess_content);
        
            // Dodaj nowe reguły do pliku .htaccess
            $new_htaccess_content = $current_htaccess_content . $gzip_compression;
        
            // Zapisz nową zawartość do pliku .htaccess
            file_put_contents($htaccess_path, $new_htaccess_content);
        }
```

I would like to make this code work only if GZIP is not already enabled on both Nginx and Apache servers. What is the best way to achieve that?